Trying to show the Annotation data on hover/mouse move CornerStoneJs
Trying to show the Annotation point's data on hover/mouse move using CornerstoneJs Library.
Github Link To Library
I am displaying probeTool Annotations when the image loads. You can see image#1 (Github link below) for reference. As you can see, there are a lot of probe points so by default, I'm showing them with "textBoxVisibility: false". In the Next step, I'm trying to show each point's data when hovering over the point.
I tried the MOUSE_MOVE event but this event keeps occurring with no annotation details like Annotation UID so I set "textBoxVisibility: true" based on Annotation UID.
I tried ANNOTATION_RENDERED Event too because this event successfully occurs when you hover over the point. But the issue with the event is, that it still doesn't have the Annotation details like UID so that I can set "textBoxVisibility: true".
I explored other events too but neither worked.
Is there any other way to achieve this? Or any other event that lets me know that this point got hovered with annotation details (UID). I tried the community forum too but did not get any response.
The current behavior:
I tried MOUSE_MOVE and ANNOTATION_RENDERED Events to show point data only when the mouse moves on that point But these events are not returning any annotation details like (UID) to set the annotation textBoxVisibility: true.
The expected behavior:
I want to show annotation point data only when the mouse moves to that point.
Opened an issue request on their Github Repo too but did not get any help.
GitHub Issue
